# wxWidgets how to change button look

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am a newbie with wxWidgets. I don't know how to change the color of a focused button. When I clicked once on the button, it stays blue. How can I change is color ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

wxWidgets is, above all, about having the *native* look and feel, so the focused buttons should be blue or whatever is appropriate for the current platform/theme. If you absolutely need to, you can change the buttons colours using the appropriate methods (`SetBackgroundColour()` and `SetForegroundColour()`) but they're not even guaranteed to work for all native controls under all platforms.

Comment: What if I want to un-focus the button ?

Comment: Then you need to set the focus to something else using `SetFocus()`.

Comment: @VZ. the focus border still persists on all windows which were focused at least once